# Tab-delimited file using csv.reader not delimiting where I expect it to

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I am trying to loop through a tab-delimited file of election results using Python. The following code does not work, but when I use a local file with the same results (the commented out line), it does work as expected.

The only thing I can think of is some headers or content type I need to pass the url, but I cannot figure it out.

Why is this happening?

```
import csv
import requests

r = requests.get('http://vote.wa.gov/results/current/export/MediaResults.txt') 
data = r.text
#data = open('data/MediaResults.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Results in:

```
...
['', '']
['', '']
['2']
['3']
['1']
['1']
['8']
['', '']
['D']
['a']
['v']
['i']
['d']
[' ']
['F']
['r']
['a']
['z']
['i']
['e']
['', '']
...
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

so whats happening, well, a call to `help` may shed some light.

```
>>> help(csv.reader)
 reader(...)
    csv_reader = reader(iterable [, dialect='excel']
                            [optional keyword args])
        for row in csv_reader:
            process(row)

    The "iterable" argument can be any object that returns a line
    of input for each iteration, such as a file object or a list.  The
    optional "dialect" parameter is discussed below.  The function
    also accepts optional keyword arguments which override settings
    provided by the dialect.
```

so it appears that `csv.reader` expects an iterator of some kind which will return a line, but we are passing a string which iterates on a char bases which is why its parsing character by character, one way to fix this would be to generate a temp file, but we don't need to, we just need to pass *any* iterable object.

note the following, which simply splits the string to a list of lines, before its fed to the reader.

```
import csv
import requests

r = requests.get('http://vote.wa.gov/results/current/export/MediaResults.txt') 
data = r.text
reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    print row
```

this seems to work.

I also recommend using `csv.DictReader` its quite useful.

```
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(data.splitlines(), delimiter='\t')
>>> for row in reader:
...      print row
{'Votes': '417141', 'BallotName': 'Michael Baumgartner', 'RaceID': '2', 'RaceName': 'U.S. Senator', 'PartyName': '(Prefers Republican Party)', 'TotalBallotsCastByRace': '1387059', 'RaceJurisdictionTypeName': 'Federal', 'BallotID': '23036'}
{'Votes': '15005', 'BallotName': 'Will Baker', 'RaceID': '2', 'RaceName': 'U.S. Senator', 'PartyName': '(Prefers Reform Party)', 'TotalBallotsCastByRace': '1387059', 'RaceJurisdictionTypeName': 'Federal', 'BallotID': '27435'}
```

basically it returns a dictionary for every row, using the header as the key, this way we don't need to keep track of the order but instead just the name making a bit easier for us  ie `row['Votes']` seems more readable then `row[4]`...

Answer (score 8):

This works perfectly:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('./MediaResults.txt'),
                    delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    print row
```

The first parameter to `csv.reader`should be:

> any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string
>   each time its **next**() method is called

as per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html), and you are passing a string, not a file object. A string behaves as a list of single characters hence the behavior you are observing.

Answer (score 6):

**Simple problem:** The *csv.reader* didn't expect a string for its input.

**Simple solution:**  Change the input to: `data.splitlines()`.

The csv reader expects an iterable that returns lines one at a time.  A string, unfortunately, iterates a character at a time.   To solve the problem, use *splitlines()* to turn the string into a list of lines:

```
reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to sniff the dialect through the csv API:

```
csvfile = open("example.csv", "rb")
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
```

This will produce the correct output.

See also

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer

Comment: The original is actually that you are passing the data directly to the  reader() constructor instead of file handle.