# Read and export a single column from a tab-separated file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a many large tab-separated files saved as `.txt`, which each have seven columns with the following headers:

```
#column_titles = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "text"]
```

I would like to simply extract the final column named `text` and save it into a new file with each row being a row from the original file, while are all strings.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136850/tab-delimited-file-using-csv-reader-not-delimiting-where-i-expect-it-to), as `splitlines()` was not necessary in my case. Only the order of things needed to be improved

Based on -[several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022675/write-each-list-as-a-column-in-csv-table) - [other](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) - [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856296/parsing-csv-tab-delimited-txt-file-with-python), here is my current attempt:

```
import csv

# File names: to read in from and read out to
input_file = "tester_2014-10-30_til_2014-08-01.txt"
output_file = input_file + "-SA_input.txt"

## ==================== ##
##  Using module 'csv'  ##
## ==================== ##
with open(input_file) as to_read:
    reader = csv.reader(to_read, delimiter = "\t")

    desired_column = [6]        # text column

    for row in reader:
    myColumn = list(row[i] for i in desired_column)

with open(output_file, "wb") as tmp_file:
    writer = csv.writer(tmp_file)

for row in myColumn:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

What I am getting, is simply the text field from the 2624th row form my input file, with each of the letters in that string being separated out:

```
H,o,w, ,t,h,e, ,t.e.a.m, ,d,i,d, ,T,h,u,r,s,d,a,y, ,-, ,s,e,e , ,h,e,r,e
```

I know very little in the world of programming is random, but this is definitely strange!

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059390/parsing-a-tab-separated-file-in-python) is pretty similar to my needs, but misses the writing and saving parts, which I am also not sure about.

I have looked into using the `pandas` toolbox (as per one of those links above), but I am unable to due my Python installation, so please only solutions using `csv` or other built in modules!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tab-delimited file using csv.reader not delimiting where I expect it to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136850/tab-delimited-file-using-csv-reader-not-delimiting-where-i-expect-it-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must process the file one row at a time: read, parse and write.

```
import csv

# File names: to read in from and read out to
input_file = "tester_2014-10-30_til_2014-08-01.txt"
output_file = input_file + "-SA_input.txt"

## ==================== ##
##  Using module 'csv'  ##
## ==================== ##
with open(input_file) as to_read:
    with open(output_file, "wb") as tmp_file:
        reader = csv.reader(to_read, delimiter = "\t")
        writer = csv.writer(tmp_file)

        desired_column = [6]        # text column

        for row in reader:     # read one row at a time
            myColumn = list(row[i] for i in desired_column)   # build the output row (process)
            writer.writerow(myColumn) # write it
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Worked without my having to change a thing. I had all the right ingredients there, just the wrong recipe in my head.

Comment: Would you mind editing your code to highlight for me exactly where the "read, parse, write" steps occur?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this simple solution:

```
    text_strings = [] # empty array to store the last column text
    with open('my_file') as ff:
        ss = ff.readlines() # read all strings in a string array 

    for s in ss:
        text_strings.append(s.split('\t')[-1]) # last column to the text array



    with open('out_file') as outf:
        outf.write('\n'.join(text_strings)) # write everything to output file
```

Using the list comprehension, you can translate the last columns of `ss` strings to `text_strings` faster and in one line:

```
    text_strings = [k.split("\t")[-1] for k in ss]
```

There are other simplifications possible, you get the idea)

The problem in your code appears at these two lines:

```
        for row in reader:
        myColumn = list(row[i] for i in desired_column)
```

First, there is no indentation, so there is nothing happening. Actually, on my computer, it throws an error, so there is a possibility that it is a typo. But in this case, at each step of the for-loop, you overwrite the `myColumn` value with that coming from the new row, hence in the end you have a string from the last row of the file. 
Second, `list` applied to a string (as in your code), converts the string to the list of chars:

```
    In [5]: s = 'AAAA'

    In [6]: list(s)
    Out[6]: ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

which is exactly what you see in the output.

Comment: Hmm, with that sample input it could work, but a csv file could be much more complex. How would you process commas (`,`) or new lines escapes in double quotes ? csv module exists because it correctly deals with all that corner cases

Comment: @pausag - That indentation error was from my bad copy/paste of my code - it isn't in my file. Your example isn't working for me, throwing the error: `**ff.write('\n'.join(text_strings)) # write everything to output file
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file**`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Good point, and for csv input one should of course account for these. The given problem is however states that there are "large txt tab separated files", so I do not see point of using csv here. BTW, I also did not note the tab separator in the problem. Edit the answer.

Comment: @DexterMorgan, You are write, this is my typo. there should be `outf.write(...)`, not `ff`. Edited the post

Comment: I did edit your comma to a `\t`, but I still got the same error as before. The answer from Serge has been accepted, but thanks for teaching me something new about `readlines()`, nevertheless!